# использование аргумента key при написании функции python

Tags: python, функции

есть некая функция:

```
def more_than(a,b, key=None):
    return a > b

result = more_than(4, -6, abs)
```

в результате необходимо чтобы функция учитывала аргумент key, и сравнивала числа по абсолютам.

как это сделать?

Answer (score 8):

Вы можете попробовать сделать что-то подобное:

```
def more_than(a, b, key=None):
    if key is not None:
        return key(a) > key(b)
    return a > b
```

В таком случае вы получите следующий результат:

```
print(more_than(4, -6))  # --> True
print(more_than(4, -6, abs))  # --> False
```

Здесь вы в функцию `more_than` передаёте третьим аргументом функцию `abs` (именно передаёте, а не вызываете). Внутри функции `more_than` вы уже вызываете функцию `abs`, обращаясь к ней через "псевдоним" `key`.

Comment: В принципе, условие можно сократить до `if key:`

Comment: @CrazyElf, `if key:` и `if key is not None:` **не то же самое**. В ответе **правильно** применена вторая форма для отсутствия параметра.

Comment: @MarianD Не тоже самое только в случае заведомой зловредной передачи в метод чего-то отличного от функции, например, пустого списка. В случае передачи либо не передачи ссылки на функцию работать будет одинаково.

Comment: @CrazyElf, по моему нужно соблюдать рекомендации для чистоты кода. Всегда. Нет в этом случае не надо, а в другом да.

Answer (score 5):

Без `None`:

```
def more_than(a, b, key=lambda x: x):
    return key(a) > key(b)
```

Comment: Прикольный вариант )